# In Vue is, how can I view data that's stored on another devices local storage

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to have multiple components each store data on the local storage and have one major component that can route to each one of them and view the data they save on the local storage. Is it even possible, and can it be implemented on multiple users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think storing data on localStorage depends on the component.
You store the data on the window.localStorage and can get the data anywhere you like.

Example

```
// Component 1
window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
```

```
// Component 2
window.localStorage.getItem('key') // value
```

Comment: So using a route I can get the localStorage of any and all components?

Comment: Sorry i don't get your question here.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Meant to ask if I can use Vue router to call those components from another URL and if I'll still get the data stored

Comment: Through vue router you are going to call the component. In that component if you are getting the data from the local storage like this - `window.localStorage.getItem('keyname')` you are going to get the data.

Comment: You were really helpful. Thanks a lot Mohib, now I can do what I wanted to.